# weird bug in my stopwatch

Tags: javascript, jquery

**PREVIOUS BUG:** In my [stopwatch here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/8qmyg/24/), if I pause and resume rapidly even before the first second is up, it doesnt update the `seconds` in the stopwatch. So, to fix this I did:

```
            if (milliseconds >= 1000){
                milliseconds %= 1000;
                seconds++;
            }
```

**NEW BUG:** Now, it updates the second apropriately. However, if I just start the stopwatch (without pausing), it skips the first second and directly makes it 2 seconds. 1 second is never displayed. (Please try it yourself if you cant understand what I am saying).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/8qmyg/21/)

How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem behaviour you describe. That is, in the demo from your first link I paused and restarted quickly and everything worked correctly. (I tried a number of times.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Just start the stopwatch and observe the seconds part of it.

Comment: Almost right ... it seems like the seconds are updating some milliseconds (more than 100) too early. And after some tries I can reproduce the issue that second #1 is skipped

Comment: @RahulDesai please don't use `click` for milliseconds time-based stopwatch, but `mousedown`. (I'll leave it to you to guess why)

Comment: In my opinion, the question is not off topic. I have laready updated the question along with the links. Please recheck. :)

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I did see the problem in your second demo where the seconds skipped to 2. But as I said, the first demo worked fine as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Never forget the radix in parseInt

   ```
   var stringToInt = parseInt(yourString, 10);
   ```
2. You are starting an interval, but at some point you are only clearing a timeout. Use clearInterval instead

   ```
   clearInterval(timeUpdate);
   ```

EDIT: The seconds issue: Let's check your code for `timeElapsed == 1000`. First, you set the seconds to

```
    seconds = parseInt(timeElapsed / 1000, 10) + prev_seconds;
```

which results in `seconds == 1`

Then you add another `1` to the seconds if `milliseconds >= 1000`

```
    if (milliseconds >= 1000){
       milliseconds %= 1000;
       seconds++;
    }
```

The same happens to the minutes and hours, by the way.

EDIT2: The pause/resume issue. Let's pause the imaginary watch at 01:437 and resume it.

timeElapsed will start counting at 0. After 563 milliseconds it should switch to 2 seconds and 000 millis. But what happens?

```
    seconds = parseInt(timeElapsed / 1000, 10) + prev_seconds;
```

This will result in `seconds == 1` for `timeElapsed == 563`. Correctly it should be more like

```
    seconds = Math.floor((parseInt(timeElapsed, 10) + prev_milliseconds) / 1000) + prev_seconds;
```

The same obviously counts for minutes and hours.

The resulting [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmyg/26/)

Comment: What is the significance of adding `radix ` as `10`?

Comment: @RahulDesai - Prior to ECMAScript 5, if the string began with "0", the radix was assumed 8 (octal), which just caused all sorts of problems. To this day, if the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal). It's best to define it, just to be safe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix

Comment: For numbers with leading zeros (happens a lot in your example) like `012` you will get unexpected results if you omit the radix, because parseInt will interpret those numbers with radix 8 instead of 10, so `012` will become decimal 10

Comment: @RahulDesai if you set `8` means you want a value **Octal** based :) you want decimals right? and no issues with possible leading `0`. `parseInt` accepts 2 values and it's better to use the second one called `radix` parameter.